# How to fill NA in R for quasi-same row?

Tags: r, duplicates, na

I'm looking for a way to fillNA in `duplicated()` rows. There are totally same rows and at one time there is a NA, so I decide to fill this one by value of complete row but I don't see how to deal with it.

Using the `duplicated()` function, I could have a data frame like that:

```
 df <- data.frame(
   Year = rnorm(5), 
   hour = rnorm(5), 
   LOT = rnorm(5), 
   S123_AA = c('ABF4576','ABF4576','ABF4576','ABF4576','ABF4576'), 
   S135_AA = c('ABF5403',NA,'ABF5403','ABF5403','ABF5403'), 
   S13_BB = c('BF50343','BF50343','BF50343','BF50343',NA),  
   S1763_BB = c('AA3489','AA3489','AA3489','AA3489','AA3489'), 
   S173_BB = c('BQA0478','BQA0478','BQA0478','BQA0478','BQA0478'),
   S234543 = c('AD4352','AD4352','AD4352','AD4352','AD4352'),
   S1265UU5 = c('AZERTY', 'AZERTY', 'AZERTY', 'AZERTY','AZERTY')
 )
```

The rows are similar, so how could I feel the NA by the value of the preceding raw (which is not an NA) ? There is no `complete.cases()`rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the data and find the first none NA value and replace the NA values with that value

```
# Loop through the data
for(c in 1:ncol(df)) {
    vals <- df[,c]
    noneNA <- vals[!is.na(vals)][1]
    vals[is.na(vals)] <- noneNA
    df[,c] <- vals
}
```

Or alternatively you could review your data element by element and take a none NA value from either above or below the relevant cell using nested for loops.

```
for(c in 1:ncol(df)) {
    for(r in 1:nrow(df)) {
        if (is.na(df[r,c])) {
            nearVals <- df[c(r-1, r+1),c]
            noneNA <- nearVals[!is.na(nearVals)][1]
            df[r,c] <- noneNA
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is that there is no `complete.cases()` rows. The value could be taken on the previous or on the third following rows

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just change the `(r-1, r+1)` part. Do you know any function to 'replace' this subset in a full data frame ? here it's only similar row and I want to reintegrate it in the full df given 5 or more keys for a row.

Comment: The code here loops through the full dataset. The statement df[r,c] <- ... overwrites the value currently in the data frame. What else are you looking to replace?

Comment: My df here is a subset of a full other one. Here it's just similar rows.

Comment: In that case it sounds like your example data it not fully representative of the problem you're trying to solve. It's awesome you have the example in the question. Is there any way you could adapt it to include dissimilar rows like in the full dataset?

Answer (score 1):

reading your question made me think of an [imputation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)) for the dataframe.

In other terms you need to fill the NAs with some sort of value to be able to "save"  records in the dataframe. The simplest way is to select the value of a particular column by searching the mean (when dealing with cardinal values) or the mode (when dealing with categorical values) [you may also execute a regression, but I guess it's a more complex method].

In this case we may choose the mode replacement because the attributes are categorical. By running your code we obtain the dataframe `df`:

```
         Year       hour         LOT S123_AA S135_AA  S13_BB S1763_BB S173_BB S234543 S1265UU5
1 -0.32837526  0.7930541 -1.10954824 ABF4576 ABF5403 BF50343   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
2  0.55379245 -0.7320060 -0.95088434 ABF4576    <NA> BF50343   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
3  0.36442118  0.9920967 -0.07345038 ABF4576 ABF5403 BF50343   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
4 -0.02546781 -0.1127828 -1.78241434 ABF4576 ABF5403 BF50343   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
5  1.92550340 -1.0531371  0.88318695 ABF4576 ABF5403    <NA>   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
```

We can then create a function to calculate the mode of a particular column:

```
getmode <- function(v) {
uniqv <- unique(v)
uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

And then use it to fill the missing values. Below the code to impute the missing values for the column `S135_AA` (I created a new dataframe named `workdf`) :

```
workdf <- df
workdf[is.na(workdf$S135_AA),c('S135_AA')] <- getmode(workdf[,'S135_AA'])
```

This is the output where you can see that the column `S135_AA` NAs took the most recurring value of the colum:

```
         Year       hour         LOT S123_AA S135_AA  S13_BB S1763_BB S173_BB S234543 S1265UU5
1 -0.32837526  0.7930541 -1.10954824 ABF4576 ABF5403 BF50343   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
2  0.55379245 -0.7320060 -0.95088434 ABF4576 ABF5403 BF50343   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
3  0.36442118  0.9920967 -0.07345038 ABF4576 ABF5403 BF50343   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
4 -0.02546781 -0.1127828 -1.78241434 ABF4576 ABF5403 BF50343   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
5  1.92550340 -1.0531371  0.88318695 ABF4576 ABF5403    <NA>   AA3489 BQA0478  AD4352   AZERTY
```

If your objective was data cleaning I guess that you should use an imputation method to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for your really explicit answer. Just a question, here it's a subset where all rows was similar, but is there anyway to deal with NA on the full DF ? where there is several different group of 'same' raws ? How the mode could work on it ?

Comment: As an example: you're considering the situation where the `S135_AA` contained different values and not only "ABF5403" ? In that case the mode will take the most frequent value and will impute it. The fact is that from your starting dataframe you have NAs, so if you want to keep a particular data point you have to make a choice on a value to attribute to them, but only one value can be imputed. Otherwise you'll have to drop that data point.

Comment: Ok I see, I will take a look to `missForest()` to see if it can be helpful or not in m case

Comment: You may also have a look at [kNN](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-use-of-knn-for-missing-values-cf33d935c637) for imputing missing values and, if you wish to have a nice visualization plot for reports, at [`vis_miss`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/visdat/versions/0.5.1/topics/vis_miss).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
library(zoo)

# get cols with missing values
na_cols <- names(df)[colSums(is.na(df)) > 0]

# fill the missing value backwards
for (i in na_cols){
    df[[i]] <- na.locf(df[[i]])
}
```